# Grouping hashes together to concat a key's values

Tags: ruby, reduce

I have an array of hashes like the following:

```
records = [
    { id: "PU525", note: "Foo" },
    { id: "PU525", note: "Bar" },
    { id: "DT525", note: "Hello World" },
    { id: "PU680", note: "Fubar" }
]
```

The end result should be:

```
result = [
    { id: "PU525", note: "FooBar" },
    { id: "DT525", note: "Hello World" },
    { id: "PU680", note: "Fubar" }
]
```

I started playing a little bit with `Enumerable#group_by` with the following:

```
results = records.group_by { |record| record[:id] }

# Results in:
# {
#     "PU525": [
#         { id: "PU525", note: "Foo" },
#         { id: "PU525", note: "Bar" }
#     ],
#     "DT525": { id: "DT525", note: "Hello World" },
#     "PU680": { id: "PU680", note: "Fubar" }
# }
```

The next step would be to use inject to reduce the data down further, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way to reduce down the original array to what I'm looking for as a result without so many steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly done:

```
records = [ 
    { id: "PU525", note: "Foo" },
    { id: "PU525", note: "Bar" },
    { id: "DT525", note: "Hello World" },
    { id: "PU680", note: "Fubar" }
]

arr = records.group_by { |record| record[:id] }
             .map do |k, v|
                [k, v.reduce('') { |memo, h| memo + h[:note] } ] 
             end
             .map do |a| 
                { id: a.first, note: a.last }
             end
#⇒ [
#     { id: "PU525", note: "FooBar" },
#     { id: "DT525", note: "Hello World" },
#     { id: "PU680", note: "Fubar" }
# ]
```

**UPD** After all, you have me entagled with this silly `group_by` approach. Everything is just easier.

```
records.inject({}) do |memo, el| 
  (memo[el[:id]] ||= '') << el[:note]
  memo
end.map { |k, v| { id: k, note: v } }
```

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get the error `no implicit conversion of Symbol to Integer` in the reduce block. Digging in, but I'm not 100% understanding the code yet.

Comment: I accidentally posted the incorrect version, please run the updated one.

Comment: Looks like it was a compiler error of some sort. I added parens to group everything as an argument to the `.zip` method and it's doing something, but it's not the expected result. https://gist.github.com/davejlong/d7060775dc52c4342879

Comment: @DaveLong Please see an update for an easy to read correct answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa your update is wrong.. :) Giving `{"PU525"=>"FooBar", "DT525"=>"Hello World", "PU680"=>"Fubar"}`. End result OP want as _array of hashes_...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, after using `#group_by` :

```
records = [
    { id: "PU525", note: "Foo" },
    { id: "PU525", note: "Bar" },
    { id: "DT525", note: "Hello World" },
    { id: "PU680", note: "Fubar" }
]

hsh = records.group_by { |record| record[:id] }.map do |_, v|
  v.inject do |h1, h2|
    h1.update(h2) { |k, o, n| k == :note ? o << n : n }
  end
end

p hsh
# >> [{:id=>"PU525", :note=>"FooBar"}, {:id=>"DT525", :note=>"Hello World"}, {:id=>"PU680", :note=>"Fubar"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of variants of the above.

**Using [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

```
records.group_by { |h| h[:id] }.map { |id, arr|
  { id: id, note: arr.map { |h| h[:note] }.join } }
  #=> [{:id=>"PU525", :note=>"FooBar"},
  #    {:id=>"DT525", :note=>"Hello World"},
  #    {:id=>"PU680", :note=>"Fubar"}]
```

**Using [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update)** (aka `merge!`)

```
records.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:id]=>g) { |_,og,ng|
  { id: g[:id], note: og[:note]+ng[:note] } } }.values
  #=>[{:id=>"PU525", :note=>"FooBar"},
  #   {:id=>"DT525", :note=>"Hello World"},
  #   {:id=>"PU680", :note=>"Fubar"}]
```